# Can we merge spl-associated-token-account into associated-token-account?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The two tags: [spl-associated-token-account](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spl-associated-token-account) and [associated-token-account](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/associated-token-account) are the same thing.

All Associated Token Accounts on Solana are SPL Associated Token Accounts. Can we please merge them, or make one redirect to the other?

`associated-token-account` should be the main tag as the smaller term is more commonly used.